# Javascript - Why does this code blocks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I Don't get why this code blocks. I use nodejs async functions, but now I'm trying to figure out what's the essence of non-blocking programming, and how can I implement those.
This is the way I thought it would be, but Its still blocking.

```
   var async_func = function(x, func) {
        func(x+5);
    };

    setTimeout( async_func(5, function(number) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) {;}
        console.log(number);
    }), 3000);

    console.log("done");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake when using `setTimeout()` and when passing function references where you want to call a function with arguments.  This line of code:

```
setTimeout( async_func(5, function(number) {
```

executes `async_func()` immediately and then passes it's return result (which is not a function) to `setTimeout()` and that is NOT what you want.  You want to pass a function reference to `setTimeout()` so `setTimeout()` can call that function later like this:

```
var async_func = function(x, func) {
    func(x+5);
};

setTimeout( function() {
    async_func(5, function(number) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) {;}
        console.log(number);
    });
}, 3000);

console.log("done");
```

or, sometimes it's easier to understand by making your timer callback function it's own separate function with no arguments.

```
function async_func(x, func) {
    func(x+5);
}

function timer_func() {
    async_func(5, function(number) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) {;}
        console.log(number);
    });
}

setTimeout(timer_func, 3000);

console.log("done");
```

Comment: Very clear explanation! But why running my async_func alone, without a timer still blocks? I'm trying to find info on the internet but I don't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: What do you mean "blocks"?  `async_func` by itself is not an async function so of course, it should block.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var async_func = function(x, func) {
    func(x+5);
};

setTimeout(function(){
    async_func(5, function(number) {
       console.log(number);
    });
}, 3000);

console.log("done");
```

(I also removed the unnecessary `for (var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) {;}`)

**You should not call a function with arguments in setTimeout without making an anonymous or helper function... (If you really want to do it without setting another function check @Ian comments bellow.)**

If your function didn't had any arguments you could do `setTimeout(async_func, 3000);` but in this case the best thing is just to call it trough an anonymous function (or declaring a calling function above calling your function with those arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why does setTimeout can't handle a function with arguments?

Comment: **You cannot call a function with arguments in setTimeout without making an anonymous function...** well, technically you could - the first parameter of `setTimeout` can be a string, so you can construct a function call with concatenating strings and variables, like: `setTimeout("myFunction(" + var1 + ");", 200);` but that's clearly not ideal in probably any situation :)

Comment: @Ian that's a solution, but not the best approach. @JuanCruzViotti, just remove the line with `for (var x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) {;}` and it'll work without any problem. (I've updated my answer).

Comment: @Whiteagle Haha I know it's not the best approach...I'm not sure I'd ever suggest it. Although I'm sure there's a time and place it would be good for something. I just wanted to point out that the claim about calling a function with arguments in setTimeout without an anonymous function wasn't exactly right.

Comment: @Ian you're right, I was wrong while writing "can't" instead of "should" :) Updated my answer.

Comment: @JuanCruzViotti That's because `setTimeout`'s first parameter is a reference to a function **or** a string of code to execute. References to functions are only that - references. Arguments are used when you **call** a function, which you can't do when passing a reference. That's why anonymous functions are perfect for this situation.